# Cypress cy.api request fails when URL is returned by enum

Tags: javascript, api, automated-tests, cypress

When trying to make a request to API endpoint using Cypress, different results are returned when url is directly passed or from a method/enum. Not sure how to go about it as I don't want to hardcode the urls in request.

```
const SPACEID = some_space_id
const ENVIRONMENTID = development
const ENTRIES_EP = entries
const CONTENT_TYPE_EP = contentType

enum endPoints {
  entries = `https://app.contentful.com/spaces/${SPACEID}/environments/${ENVIRONMENTID}/${ENTRIES_EP}`,
  content_type = `https://app.contentful.com/spaces/${SPACEID}/environments/${ENVIRONMENTID}/${CONTENT_TYPE_EP}`,
}
 
cy.api({
    method: 'GET',
    url: String(endPoints.content_type),
    auth: {
      bearer: `SOME_TOKEN`,
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
    cy.wrap(response).as('resp')
  })
```

The code above returns some HTML content stating only Chrome, Firefox is supported.
However if I add the absolute URL in cy.api call it works fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I have compared both URLs and they are exactly same.

```
https://app.contentful.com/spaces/some_space_id/environments/development/content_types
https://api.contentful.com/spaces/some_space_id/environments/development/content_types
```

Comment: Please ignore, it was a typo that wasted a few hours of my day.

Comment: Please feel free to delete the question.